# Evaluating $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right )^3$ with Parseval's identity

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

If this were an even power it would be clear enough how to approach this, although I wouldn't be crazy about computing the Fourier transform.

For reference:
I was able to solve 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right )^2
$$
using that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is the Fourier transform of the indicator function (interval dependent on one's definition of fourier transform).

Ideally a solution to the above would make reference to this fact assuming it is still germane.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you *required* to use Parseval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few couple ways to get to the desired answer, using only standard techniques of Calculus

---

**Solution 1**

If you allow yourself to use it, this is a textbook example of when to use Integration by Parts
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3} dx = \,3\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(x)}{x^2}dx = \frac{3}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{3\sin(3x)-\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
I assume you can take it from here by applying an integral you already know.

---

**Solution 2**

We can also apply Euler's Formula to convert our integral into
$$\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{3e^{-ix}}{x^3}-\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{3e^{ix}}{x^3}-\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-3ix}}{x^3}+\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{3ix}}{x^3}$$
Each of which is trivial by using Differentiation Under the Integral Sign.
Note that we have to use the Principle Value here, as each of these doesn't normally converge